# Use jquery to get data from a csv file through http response

Tags: jquery, csv, google-chrome-extension, httpresponse

I use the jquery get method to get a response from the server.

```
$.get($url, function(data){
alert(data);
});
```

The response is a .csv file and I have no clue to get the data. 
When I use the alert(data), it prints a null value.   I use this for a chrome extension. I have added the 
    "permissions": [
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/"
    ],

in my manifest.json file. When I use safari browser in my local, it is working properly.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is missing something? Just ask it to JavaScript console!

```
  window.jqxhr = $.get(url, function() {
      console.log('readyState: ' + jqxhr.readyState);
      console.log('statusText: ' + jqxhr.statusText);
      console.log('responseText: ' + jqxhr.responseText);
      console.log('ResponseHeaders: ' + jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
  });
```

Now go to 'Wrench > Tools > JavaScript console' and see what it say. 
May it help you to figure out what's happening, if not, post the output here.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load *url*. Origin domain_name is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  This is the output i get from the js console

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin